# Java error while trying to format namenode in hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop

I am new to hadoop , i am trying to configure hadoop in ubuntu 16.4 and i am using java8. I have installed hadoop and confiured the xml files.Java 8 is also installed and when i am writing java -version it is giving

```
java version "1.8.0_151"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.151-b12, mixed mode)
```

which confirms the java is installed.

When i am writing  echo $JAVA_HOME it is giving

```
/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_151
```

I have also set the path in hadoop-env.sh file that is

```
# The java implementation to use.
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_151
export JAVA_HOME=${JAVA_HOME}
```

I have set the path inthe bashrc

```
#JAVA HOME directory setup
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_151
export JAVA_HOME
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export PATH
```

when i am trying to find the java path in the system using

```
whereis java
 it is giving
 java: /usr/bin/java /usr/share/java /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz
```

After all this i am trying to run the command

```
    hdfs namenode -format


   /home/hadoop/hadoop/bin/hdfs: line 304: /usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_151/bin/java: No such file or directory
```

Please help

Comment: Just because you set `JAVA_HOME`, doesn't mean that folder exists (or the Hadoop process has access to read it). Can you please `ls /usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_151`?

Comment: @cricket_007 actually i am not able to understand the problem

Comment: Did you run the `ls` command on that folder? Does it exist? The `hdfs` command says it does not

Comment: @cricket_007 i am gettingls: cannot access '/usr/lib/java/jdk1.8.0_151': No such file or directory

Comment: There you go. Now, you need to find where `java` is actually installed.

Comment: @cricket_007 i am getting the path as java: /usr/bin/java /usr/share/java /usr/share/man/man1/java.1.gz

Comment: `/usr/bin/java` is a symlink. Try `readlink -f $(which java)`